# PHP routers, difference between "tutorial routers" and the big one from frameworks

Tags: php, url-routing, laravel-routing

it's my first post, so tell me if i've done something wrong.

i'm trying to understand logic of big routers on github and frameworks.
I understand to routers that works like this:

***folder structure:***

```
*controllers/Home.php
*index.php
```

**index.php file, orientation code:**

```
$uri = www.xyz.com/home/default/param;

# get parts from url
$parts = explode("/", $uri);

# call controller
$controller_class = "controller_namespace\\".$parts[0];
$controller = new $controller_class;
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $parts[1]), $parts[2]);
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so on page www.xyz.com/home/default/param is called controller class home and func. default with params, in filestructure you are still on index.php file, only different controller classes is being called by url.

So, routers that i want understand works like:

```
class Home{
 Router::get("/default", function(){
 echo 'Hello';
});
Router::Dispatch();
}
```

From code that i found on [github here](https://github.com/noahbuscher/Macaw) etc. i think, the Router loads all the functions from controller and execute that one which match the url ...huh?

**Q:**
How i can execute the controller class above, when im still on index.php?

Comment: This isn’t a specific programming question. Please take the [tour](/tour) to read on what types of questions are acceptable. In the meantime, your best bet would be just to read through the code of the routers you’re interested in to get a handle on how they work—that’s how others learn how things work.